# Stubbing React useState with Sinon

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, sinon

I'm trying to stub Reacts `useState` hook with sinon but I'm running into issues.

Here's an example of my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Expand() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setExpanded(true)}>
        Expand
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I've tried mocking it using Sinon like so.

```
import * as React from 'react'; 
import {stub} from 'sinon';

const component = mount(<Expand />);
const setExpandedStub = stub();
const setStateStub = stub(React, 'useState').returns([
  null,
  setExpandedStub,
]);

component
  .find('button')
  .prop('onClick')();

t.equals(
  setExpandedStub.args[0],
  true,
  'Should set the state to true.'
);
```

The issue I'm having is that `setExpandedStub.args` never seem to return what I expect it to. Instead it comes back with `[]`. I've logged out the hook call, and it does fire in the test, but I can't seem to figure out how to get back what goes in for testing purposes. The reason I'm doing this is because I can't seem to call `component.state()` in Enzyme as it's not a class component.

Comment: Maybe your example is simplified but why do you need to stub at all? If the goal is to test that state is true after triggering a click on the button, why not just trigger the click (use simulate() instead if using enzyme)  and check the state value is true after?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It's simplified, but from my understanding you can't use Enzyme's `.state()` in a non-class component, so I'd like to see what `setExpanded` gets called with to make sure that the state is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is a little tricky to explain.  When you stub, you're stubbing a method of an object.  Thus, when you want your source code to be subjected to the stub, you'll also have to use the stubbed object there.  In this case, you'll need to call `React.useState`, rather than the destructured instance of `useState`.

This should solve your issue:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Expand() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setExpanded(true)}>
        Expand
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```